# Eclipse Java project build path using variables

Tags: eclipse

I am developing an Eclipse Java project and would like to use "variables" to point to required libraries (.jar files).

Setup:

- Machine 1: Eclipse Juno, OS X, own laptop, libs under `/mylibs`
- Machine 2: Eclipse Juno, Linux, shared machine, libs under `/sharedlibs/some/complex/path`

Source control: Mercurial

Example of libs I use:

- "${libs_base}/junit.jar"
- "${libs_base}/guava.jar"
- "${libs_base}/logging/slf4j.jar"

How can I configure the project `Build Path` to use the same "variable" for the **base** directory for libraries, pointing to different locations on different machines, but still check in my project description to source control so that when I add a new library, provided I specify its location relative to the libs **base**, it is found on both machines?

I have found the help file but could use an example, maybe even a screenshot please?

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcpathvars.htm

for instance, do I copy this model:

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcepts-exttools.htm

inside "Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables" or elsewhere?

I have done a fair bit of "blind trial and error" already.. like stitching forms like "${env:VAR}" in there..

Oh, and I suppose I should mention that I don't know how to set these Eclipse variables based on environment variables considering that my systems' environment variables are set by Bash's `.profile` and I doubt Eclipse runs a shell to source that before...

```
/org.eclipse.jdt.core/org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathVariable.my_libraries=$MY_SYS_ENV_VAR_LIBS
```

Of course, I use "Configure Build Path > Libraries > Add Variable" and then Extend from there, but still... an example would be worth a 1000 words.. (could it be that defining an Eclipse variable from which to `Extend` actual .jar references for inclusion in Build Paths just can't be based on a *system* environment variable, full stop?!)

PS: please don't ask me to just symlink things around, I am not a sysadmin on the shared machine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, extending a path variable would work perfectly for your case as you can define different base paths for each machine and reference libraries on subpaths based on that path. However if you are looking specifically to use environment variables you can try adding them to the build path this way:

1. Edit your launch configuration.
2. Go to the **Classpath** tab.
3. Click on **User Entries** and click the **Advanced** button.
4. To add a library based on a system environment variable, select **Add
   Variable String**, and in the box type:
   `${env_var:libs_base}/logging/slf4j.jar`. In this case
   `libs_base` is your environment variable and `logging/slf4j.jar` is
   the path to the jar in the subdirectory.

Comment: that's not the *build* path, that's the classpath for a launch config

Comment: @Rhubarb indeed, but the procedure is the same: once you added a path variable you refer to it using the "Extend" button in the "Add variable..." option.